# Given an unsorted array, how to remove duplicates then sort it?

Tags: c++, arrays, c

I get troubles with this, can you help me?

I remove duplicate successfully, but then I use bubble sort to sort it but it is inefficient.

How can I remove duplicate then sort it?  Using 2 functions can not bring what I desire.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int arr[100];
int n;
void RemoveDuplicate(int arr[]);
void Print(int arr[]);

int main()  
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    RemoveDuplicate(arr);
    Print(arr);
    getch();    
    return 0;
}

void Print(int arr[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}

void RemoveDuplicate(int arr[])
{
    int i,j,k;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    for(j=i+1;j<n;)
        {
        if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
            for(k=j;k<n;k++)
                {
                arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                }
            n--;
            }
        else
            j++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Flip the operations.  Sort, then remove the duplicates.  Makes it much easier.

Comment: Hint: it is usually done in the opposite direction: first sorting the sequence, than removing the duplicates. Removing duplicates in unsorted sequence is a pain.

Comment: C or C++ ? Please pick one.

Comment: I think removing duplicate before sorting is more inefficcient because It will require another memory region or slow algorithm in my quick view. Bubble sort is inefficient, so you should use faster sort algorithm for efficiency.

Comment: in c++ it is two lines with the help of algorithms, in C i don't know

Comment: By the way, don't you want the size of array after removing duplicates?

Comment: You could remove duplicates while sorting.  If you do, say, a heap sort, you can compare the item popped off the heap with the previous item in the sorted part of the array and toss the new value if it matches the previous one.

Comment: In C++ you can use `std::set` container to store unique items

Comment: In the C language, you can use `qsort` to sort the array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All example are untested and begins with the following

```
if (n<1 || n > sizeof(arr))
  return;

auto begin = std::begin(arr);
auto end = begin+n;
```

Using std::set

```
std::set<int> unique(begin, end);
std::copy(unique.begin(), unique.end(), std::begin(arr));
int size = unique.size();
```

Using heap

```
std::make_heap(begin, end);
std::sort_heap(begin, end);
auto last = std::unique(begin, end);
auto size = std::distance(begin, last);
```

Just using std::sort instead of sort_heap

```
std::sort(begin, end);
auto last = std::unique(begin, end);
auto size = std::distance(begin, last);
```

Using heap with manual pop

```
std::make_heap(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
auto first = begin;
auto last = end;
auto sorted = std::prev(last);
std::pop_heap(first, last--);  // initial value
while (first != last)
  std::pop_heap(first, last--);
  if (*last != *sorted && last != sorted)
    *--sorted = *last;
}
auto size = std::distance(sorted, end);
std::copy(sorted, end, begin); // move values to start of array
```

The condition

```
last != sorted
```

will be false until the first duplicate and true thereafter so the loop could be split in two for a possible better performance, but the branche predictor should remove most performance problems because of this.

If the number of unique values are small and in a small spread and 'n' is large use a counting array.

Example of char counting for std::vector text;

```
std::array<int,256> count;
std::vector<char> result;
for (auto ch : text)
  count[ch]++;
for (auto idx = 0; idx < count.size(); ++idx)
  if (count[idx]) 
    result.emplace_back(idx);
```

If the number of duplicates are larger but the values spread, consider using std::unordered_set instead and sort at the end.

```
std::unordered:set<int> unique(begin, end);
std::copy(unique.begin(), unique.end(), std::begin(arr));
int size = unique.size();
std::sort(begin, begin+size);
```